# C program multiply the int values of an array

Tags: int, multiplication

I'm working on an exercise about arrays and multiplying the values of the arrays. But it contains some errors and the problem is, I don't know what to change. Any help would be much appreciated with this problem.

The given code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) 
{
    int i, j ;
    int Data[15] ;
    for(i=1;i<=15;i++)
         Data[i]=i*i ;
}
```

The exercise:

*1. It contains a big error. Fix it!*

*2. There are two other things not entirely correct. What are they? (Hint: one is usually detected as a warning by the compiler, and the other is related to this).*

*3. Write one or two lines to print out the array using a for-loop.*

When I print Data[i] I get 0:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) 
{
    int i, j ;
    int Data[15] ;
    for(i=1;i<=15;i++)
         Data[i]=i*i ;

    printf("%d\n", Data[i]) ;
}
```

Comment: `int Data[15]` has indexes of `0` - `14`, so you skip the first element and go past the end. Also, after the `for` loop, `i` is 16, which is also outside the bounds of the array (the `printf` is *not* in the `for` loop).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reps to make a comment but this needs way more information to help out. What errors are you getting and what are you trying to accomplish here?

Also indexing starts from 0 usually so maybe that's screwing stuff up. You are starting from 1 just a FYI, you have to go 0-14 not 1-15